# Error while executing Python code. No module named 'angelheap'

Tags: python, gdb, reverse-engineering

When I run gdb and set breakpoint I got this Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'angelheap'
Error while executing Python code.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Looking at the github repo of `pwngdb` `angelheap` might be part of the package.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about how to install it in the official documentation that seems to be this: https://github.com/scwuaptx/Pwngdb

Installation

```
cd ~/
git clone https://github.com/scwuaptx/Pwngdb.git 
cp ~/Pwngdb/.gdbinit ~/
```

Comment: @Itra Could you please specify? Python version, Os you are running (and bits), and how you installed the nodule.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out this GitHub repo below to make sure the installation was done correctly:
https://github.com/scwuaptx/Pwngdb

Comment: try maybe: sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg gdb valgrind

Comment: Also, make sure you have an ANSI-compliant C compiler such as gcc